# Perimeter calculation in C

Tags: c, math

I'm trying to use the distance between points formula to calculate the perimeter of any geometric figure, but the function is not delivering the values it should. I have no clue of what I'm doing wrong

```
#include <math.h>

int perimeter(int flag, dot d[]){
 float result, sum1, sum2, sum3, quad1, quad2, op[flag], sum;

 for(int c=0;c<flag;c++){
    sum1=d[c+1].x-d[c].x;
    sum2=d[c+1].y-d[c].y;
    quad1=pow(sum1, 2);
    quad2=pow(sum2, 2);
    sum3=quad1+quad2;
    result=sqrt(sum3);
    op[c]=result;
 }
 for(int c=0;c<flag;c++){
    sum+=op[c];
 }return sum;
}
```

Test values:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct dot{
  float x,y;
}dot;

int main(){
  int flag=4;
  dot d[flag];
  d[0].x=9;
  d[0].y=10;
  d[1].x=21;
  d[1].y=10;
  d[2].x=21;
  d[2].y=16;
  d[3].x=9;
  d[4].y=16;

  float result, sum1, sum2, sum3, quad1, quad2, op[flag], sum=0.0;

  for(int c=0;c<flag;c++){
    sum1=d[c+1%flag].x-d[c].x;
    sum2=d[c+1%flag].y-d[c].y;
    quad1=pow(sum1, 2);
    quad2=pow(sum2, 2);
    sum3=quad1+quad2;
    result=sqrt(sum3);
    printf("distance %d: %d\n", c, result);
    sum+=result;

 }
 printf("final result: %d\n", result);
}
```

Console log(printing steps):

```
gcc version 4.6.3

distance 0: 0
distance 1: 1
distance 2: 2
distance 3: 3
final result: 26533904
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You need to give us more detail, such as the example input (in this case, the parameters to the function call), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If `flag` is the number or vertices in the polygon array then `d[c+1].x` needs to be `d[(c+1) % flag].x` and same for other.

Comment: Aside: you make life hard by building an array of each length, when you could sum them as you go. Note that `sum` is an *uninitialised variable* so there is undefined behaviour.

Comment: `sum` is not initialized

Comment: Try using meaningful variable names.  For example `sumx` instead of `sum1` and `vertices` instead of `flag`.

Comment: Note, too, that you should probably return `float`.  In my book, you should do `g/float/s//double/g` (change `float` to `double` throughout), but that's somewhat separate as an issue.  Returning `float` is rather important, I think.

Comment: Array indexing for an array of `4` elements in C runs from `0` to `3`.   Your code is setting and accessing `d[4]`.    That gives undefined behaviour.

Comment: Your revised code has `sum1=d[c+1%flag].x-d[c].x;` — but `1 % flag` is always `1`.  You need `sum1=d[(c+1)%flag].x-d[c].x;`.   Using `%d` to print a `float` value is bogus — decent compilers warn about that goof.  Also, you've radically changed the question; that is not a good idea.  Adding the MCVE shouldn't change the code from a function `perimeter()` to just `main()`. That makes the answers already given less relevant, and your question into a 'chameleon question'. I've rolled back your destructive change and then reinserted the updated code as extra information. Please do that in future.

Comment: There are lots of bugs here. One is that `d[4].y=16;` should be `d[3].y=16;`. You are also indexing past the end of the array. When you reach the last element, you need to wrap around back to the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look up the [`hypot()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/hypot.html) functions declared in the `<math.h>` header. You could end up with:

```
float perimeter(int n_dots, dot d[])
{
    float sum = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n_dots; i++)
    {
        int n = (i+1) % n_dots;
        sum += hypotf(d[n].x - d[i].x, d[n].y - d[i].y);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

If you need to report on the values calculated, you can capture the result of `hypotf()` before you add it to `sum`.

Note, too, that you should return a `float` value. In my book, you should change `float` to `double` throughout (and use `hypot()` in place of `hypotf()`), but that's somewhat separate as an issue. Returning `float` (or `double`) rather than `int` is rather important, I think.

The MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) version of your code might be:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct dot
{
    float x, y;
} dot;
float perimeter(int n_dots, dot d[]);

int main(void)
{
    enum { num_dots = 4 };
    dot d[num_dots] =
    {
        { .x =  9, .y = 10 },
        { .x = 21, .y = 10 },
        { .x = 21, .y = 16 },
        { .x =  9, .y = 16 },
    };
    printf("Perimeter: %.3f\n", perimeter(num_dots, d));
    return 0;
}

float perimeter(int n_dots, dot d[])
{
    float sum = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n_dots; i++)
    {
        int n = (i + 1) % n_dots;
        sum += hypotf(d[n].x - d[i].x, d[n].y - d[i].y);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Using a VLA prevents you using an initializer for it, so I made the array into a regular fixed size array.

Output:

```
Perimeter: 36.000
```

For the given data, this is correct (the four sides are of length 12, 6, 12, 6).

Comment: May I ask why did you use "enum" in place of int?

Comment: So I could use an initializer, because when you use `int` you create a VLA and you can't initialize a VLA.  As I noted in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize `sum` with 0.0.

Then

Replace

`op[c]=result;`

with

`sum+=result;`

You don't need the other `for` loop.

Secondly, make sure the value of the variable `flag` passed to the perimeter function is 1 less than the size of the dots array `d`.

Lastly, you need to add the distance between the last point and the first point to the sum. (After the `for` loop).

```
sum1 = d[flag+1].x - d[0].x;
sum2 = d[flag+1].y - d[0].y;
quad1=pow(sum1, 2);    
quad2=pow(sum2, 2);
sum3=quad1+quad2;
result=sqrt(sum3);
sum+=result;
```

Comment: Those are all interesting comments but `sum` is never initialized!

Comment: Yeah, the OP needs to initialize it to 0.0 for the above recommendations to work. I will update it.

Comment: `flag` needs to be the "number of dots" not one less than "size of the dots".

Comment: Why not `sum += result;`?  There's no harm in the more verbose formulation in that it will produce the same result, but it is often clearer to use the `+=` or other assignment operators since there's no question but that you're incrementing `sum`.

Comment: @WeatherVane Well, the way I am proposing the solution, it needs to be one less. See my edited answer.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler. My intention was to give OP a quick start answer. But you are right. I have edited my answer to incorporate your feedback.

Comment: Why? There is no loop in your answer. It would be easier to use a "previous index" than replicate waht is already in the loop.

Comment: @Lordie, can you describe what is not working. What is your input dot array? What is the output that you get with my above suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version, with better variable names,

```
#include <math.h>

float perimeter(int flag, dot d[]){
    float sum_x, sum_y, quad_x, quad_y, sum = 0;

    for(int c=0;c<flag;c++){
        sum_x=d[(c+1) % flag].x-d[c].x;
        sum_y=d[(c+1) % flag].y-d[c].y;
        quad_x=pow(sum_x, 2);
        quad_y=pow(sum_y, 2);
        sum += sqrt(quad_x + quad_y);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Even in C90, you could declare the variables `sum_x`, `sum_y`, `quad_x`, `quad_y` in the loop as you initialize them with the calculations.  This limits the scope of the variables, which is good practice (though what you've got is hardly a serious problem).  Using the `hypotf()` function instead of doing the calculation piecemeal as in your code simplifies life (and avoids avoidable overflows — even if `sum_x` or `sum_y` or both are large enough that their square overflows the range of `float`, the value returned by `hypotf()` will be correct).